# terraform Output eip public IP addresses

Tags: terraform

Trying to figure out how to output the eip public IP addresses rather then the eip id. I have this code in the output file within the VPC module.

```
output "instance_eip_public_ip"{
  value = aws_eip.instance_eip.*.public_ip
}
```

But I am using the root module to call the VPC module. So how do I get the output of the eip public ip addresses when applying the root module?

I wrote this code but it gives me the allocation id of the eip.

```
  output "eip_allocation_id"{
    value = module.vpc.instance_eip.*.id
  }
```

So do I need to write this as:

```
output "eip_public_ip"{
  value = module.vpc.instance_eip.public_ip
}
```

I get confused on how to carry outputs from one module to another.

Answer (score 0):

You can just write module.vpc.instance_eip_public_ip

Comment: So how does module.vpc.instance_eip.public_ip become module.vpc.instance_eip_public_ip?

Comment: Based on you definition of your output in the module. output "instance_eip_public_ip"{
  value = aws_eip.instance_eip.*.public_ip
}

Comment: Does the output name have to be the exact same in the root module output? 

output "**instance_eip_public_ip**"{
  value = aws_eip.instance_eip.*.public_ip
}

Answer (score 0):

you can call the module variable in the following way. based on some other module I have on hand.

code in your file "./modules/glue_database/output.tf"

```
output "glue_temp_bucket_id" {
   description = "The name of the Glue Temp bucket."
   value       = element(concat(aws_s3_bucket.glue_temp_bucket.*.id, [""]), 0)
}
```

call module in your main.tf:

```
module "glue_database" {
   source      = "./modules/glue_database"
   ... module variables you need to pass
}
```

usage of your variable in other parts of main.tf

```
module.glue_database.glue_temp_bucket_id
```